# What is $product in bundle id

Tags: objective-c, xcode, app-store

I want to submit my application to appstore.

I saw this screen shot

[image]

So what is ${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier}

Is it the name of the executable?

Is there  a way to change it?

Should I just hardcode the ${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier} and put actual product name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're correct that "product" is the executable name, but even if it isn't you won't have any problem with hard coding your bundle ID, I always do this. (true or not) I feel like it makes the process more fool proof.

**EDIT:** It seems like this is automatically set to the name of the project.

[image]

Comment: It is indeed auto-set at creation of project. Additionally, `${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier}` is the value of `${PRODUCT_NAME}` filtered so it is a valid RFC-1034 identifier (some characters are not allowed in these).

Answer (score 1):

It's not the name of the project.  A project can have multiple targets, each producing different products.

[PRODUCT_NAME](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/1-Build_Setting_Reference/build_setting_ref.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003931-CH3-SW83) is a build setting.